# Configuration of QGIS Server with Apache Web Server on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: installation, qgis-server

I have installed QGIS Server(version 2.X) on my machine (Win. 7 64 bit OS & installed on C:\OSGeo4W64) while installing I found that for 64 bit Apache web server was not available hence its separately installed on C drive (C:\Apache24)

Now tested Apache server installation and it works successfully in web browser for port 80.

I am following [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86348/adding-qgis-server-to-an-existing-windows-web-server) and [this link](http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/) for installation reference so where should I put "OSGeoW64" folder in Apache web server, to test `http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&` this URL?

Any help will be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure your configuration will work. It will end up as a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit binaries.

You can install 32-bit Apache, QGIS and QGIS Server into `C:\OSGEO4W\` and place the files in the usual locations.

This will not harm your 64-bit installation of QGIS in `C:\OSGEO4W64\`.

See also [Installing Qgis Server on Windows 7 Machine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34884/installing-qgis-server-on-windows-7-machine)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Its works perfectly!!! So assume that QGIS Server 64 bit setup is having problem but you install 32 bit version top of 64 bit it works : ) Great !!