# QGIS Web Client 2 connection time out?

Tags: apache, qgis-web-client

I have recently installed QGIS Server and Web Client 2 in the hopes of being able to share my map, that I made in QGIS, with some clients.

I've started my app with yarn and I'm now at a point where I can open the site on my local machine using the URL below:

```
localhost:8081
```

but when I try to access it from a remote computer in my network:

```
mycomputerIP:8081
```

I get an error saying that the connection has timed out.

There could be a problem with the Web Client 
since I successfully called:

```
mycomputername/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
```

from the remote computer.

How can I access the website from a remote computer?

Answer (score 2):

[QGIS WebClient 2](https://github.com/qgis/qwc2-demo-app) is abit different. When using yarn start, you only start the application, but not really serve it. If you used the old QGIS Webclient then you should have your Apache server. This server will serve your webpages around your network/s.

So if your yarn start works, simply stop it and then type:

```
yarn run prod
```

This will create your actual application inside the prod folder. Now we simply move this folder to your htdocs so apache will serve it.

That's it, now your new client will be accessible across your network.
You should access it on:

```
mycomputerIP:<PortWhereApacheListens>/prod
```

If this is your first time using the client, you will need a webserver to serve your website. To set up apache and the qgis-server try reading [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95150/configuration-of-qgis-server-with-apache-web-server-on-windows-7-64-bit).